# How to stop a Zebra Printer RW 420 from automatically feeding lots of extra paper when issuing command printImage from printer.getGraphicsUtil?

Tags: android, zebra-printers

I am using a zebra RW420 in an android project and I am coding and I find that even when simply testing the printer using the ZSDK Developer Demos the printer is printing lots of extra paper when it is issued a print command. In this case I am testing out the signature capture and print demo. I do find that if I connect it to the computer and print a label created using Zebra Designer it prints the label properly with no extra paper (in fact i wouldn't mind a couple of millimeters extra in that case).

If any one knows how to save some trees here that would be great!

The code in question is:

```
connection.open();
ZebraPrinter printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(connection);
GraphicsUtil g = printer.getGraphicsUtil();
Bitmap image = signatureArea.getBitmap();

g.printImage(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), false);

connection.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the keyword "`FORM`" in your CPCL label? It's usually before PRINT

This tells the printer to form feed after printing to the top-of-form setting the printer is configured to.  To disable it, you can remove the `FORM` keyword from your format if you don't need it, or you can set the `top-of-form` to 0.

```
! U1 getvar "media.tof"
```

will show you what your top-of-form is currently set to

```
! U1 setvar "media.tof" "0"
```

will set it to 0, so that the `FORM` will feed 0 dots

Comment: Hi @OTisler, I have added the code I am using. As you can see I am not using CPCL code directly. From what I can tell the printImage command adds it for me. I am going to do some playing around with your thought process though and see where it leads me. Thanks.

Comment: Turns out this works (if added before calling printImage(): connection.write("! U1 JOURNAL\r\n! U1 SETFF 50 2\r\n".getBytes());

Comment: What if the media is bar-sense or bar-sense with LABEL ? how can we prevent extra feeding after the black mark is encountered ?

Answer (score 3):

this works perfect for me:

```
Connection connection = getZebraPrinterConn();
connection.open();
ZebraPrinter printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(connection);
// this is very important which sets automatic heigth setting for label
connection.write("! U1 JOURNAL\r\n! U1 SETFF 50 2\r\n".getBytes());
printer.printImage(new ZebraImageAndroid(bitmap), 0, 0,800, 1200, false);
connection.close();
```

This wont waste paper and it will print upto the availability of text/data

Assume that you have to print a receipt of width 800 and height 1200 , but it is printing a receipt of height approx. 1800 . so there is a wastage of a receipt for 600 px of white space to make use of that wastage you can use above code.

Comment: Explain your code a little. Code only answers are not appreciated.

Comment: Assume that you have to print a receipt of width 800 and height 1200 , but  it is printing a receipt of height approx. 1800 . so there is a wastage of a receipt for  600   px of white space to make use of that wastage you can use above code.