# zebra iMZ220 Prints blank image when label size small

Tags: ios, objective-c, printing, zebra-printers

I'm using GraphicUtil from the zebra Library to print an image, I have reciept tape in the printer and the printer set to a 2" x 2" size with continuous feed. The Image I'm trying to print is 403x203 pixels, and I'm scaling it down in the print call.

`UIImage * test = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
success = [[self.printer getGraphicsUtil] printImage:[test CGImage] atX:0 atY:0 withWidth:300 withHeight:150 andIsInsideFormat:NO error:&error];`

If I configure the printer back to default it prints the image but in the middle of a long section with blank before and after. In the near future I'm going to switch over to labels of some sort instead of tape so I was hoping to emulate the size ~2x1".

Is there something I'm missing as far as configuration and positioning goes?

This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384176/zebra-imz320-image-printing-feeds-too-much-paper?rq=1) but that answer didn't seem to work for me.

EDIT:
Turns out the problem was a call to a function to convert PDFs to UIImages and the context flipping and translating in that. Once I removed that superfluous call this started working right. Thanks to those that looked and thought about my issue.

Comment: You mention that the other Stack Overflow answer doesn't help.  Perhaps you are using a different model/language.  What model/language are you using?  You can find the language by sending the SGD devices.languages.