# Zebra ZQ520 printing feeds too much paper

Tags: android, printing, zebra-printers, zpl

I found a partial answer to my problem in [Zebra iMZ320 image printing feeds too much paper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384176/zebra-imz320-image-printing-feeds-too-much-paper):

```
! U1 setvar "ezpl.media_type" "continuous"
! U1 setvar "zpl.label_length" "500"
```

but how to configure printer if, for every print job, the size (height) changes? for example, in my case, I need to print a timesheet report, and I want that the user indicates the number of rows to print every time.
I must calculate and configure the size of printing area every time (from my android app), or is possible to say to printer "print everything between ^XA to ^XZ without feed blank paper" ?? thanks!

Comment: So you have a endless paper in your printer and not single labels?

Comment: yes, a roll of continuous paper, I can print a label between 1 to 32000 dots, the length is decided at runtime by request of app users

Comment: found the answer: the way to do this is exactly to set every time the height of printing area, also inline with the command ^LL ( https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO6705 )

Comment: Hey, great. You can answer your own question and accept this.

Comment: yes, sure, it could be useful for someone. done, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer: the way to do this is exactly to set every time the height of printing area, also inline with the command ^LL ( [km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO6705](http://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO6705) )