# Zebra MZ320 - feeds few lines after black mark is found

Tags: zebra-printers

I am working with **Zebra MZ320** printer to integrate Black mark. I am facing issue when black mark is set to True. The printer feeds 2-3 line after black mark is encountered on paper

The command used to calibrate black mark successfully :

```
! DF CONFIG.SYS                        
! UTILITIES                                    
BAR-SENSE
LABEL                                     
PRINT
```

Sample print text :

```
! 0 200 200 700 1
COUNTRY UK
COUNTRY UK
TEXT 4 0 0 0 -----------------------------------
TEXT 4 0 0 20 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TEXT 4 0 0 50 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TEXT 4 0 0 80 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TEXT 4 0 0 120 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TEXT 4 0 0 150 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TEXT 4 0 0 180 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TEXT 4 0 0 220 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TEXT 4 0 0 260 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TEXT 4 0 0 310 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TEXT 4 0 0 350 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

! DF CONFIG.SYS
! UTILITIES
BAR-SENSE
SETFF 0 0
LABEL
PRINT
```

I have seen many links that prevent extra feeding but they work with *FORM / Continuous*  mode

Already visited and tried these links :

- [Zebra iMZ320 image printing feeds too much paper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384176/zebra-imz320-image-printing-feeds-too-much-paper)
- [Stop my mobile printer from feeding extra paper using continuous roll?](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO8293&actp=LIST)
- [Stop a Zebra Printer from automatically feeding lots of extra pape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878012/how-to-stop-a-zebra-printer-rw-420-from-automatically-feeding-lots-of-extra-pape)

It seems I am missing some configuration while sending commands to printer. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Is the sense of the label gap correct. If, for example, the printer is looking for a white gap, it may use the end of the mark instead of the beginning as the indicator, and then move forward to what it thinks is the next label.

Comment: If the dimentions in your commands does not match the dimentions of the physical medium in your printer, you may get the effects that you explain above.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes these printers need calibration, did you calibrate it? See the calibration procedure in the user manual.

You can recalibrate the printer with Zebra Tools but also with ZPL commands. Sometimes only recalibration with ZPL commands helps.